# flutter TabBarView doesn't change by TabController

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to programmatically change between tabs inside the app.
tabController.animateTo() only change the TabBar, but not TabBarView.

Here's my example, and it should animateTo LEFT whenever I swipe to the RIGHT because the tab change listener automatically call animateTo(0).
But only the TabBar changes to LEFT (as expected), not the TabBarView (not expected). I want both change to LEFT.

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: new MyTabbedPage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyTabbedPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyTabbedPage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyTabbedPageState createState() => new _MyTabbedPageState();
}

class _MyTabbedPageState extends State<MyTabbedPage> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  final List<Tab> myTabs = <Tab>[
    new Tab(text: 'LEFT'),
    new Tab(text: 'RIGHT'),
  ];

  TabController _tabController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _tabController = new TabController(vsync: this, length: myTabs.length);
    _tabController.addListener(_handleTabChange);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _tabController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _handleTabChange() {
    _tabController.animateTo(0);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text("Tab demo"),
        bottom: new TabBar(
          controller: _tabController,
          tabs: myTabs,
        ),
      ),
      body: new TabBarView(
        controller: _tabController,
        children: myTabs.map((Tab tab) {
          return new Center(child: new Text(tab.text));
        }).toList(),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () => _tabController.animateTo((_tabController.index + 1) % 2), // Switch tabs
        child: new Icon(Icons.swap_horiz),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: comment "_tabController.animateTo(0);" in _handleTabChange() it will work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because you have a listener on every change `_tabController.addListener(_handleTabChange);` and every time you call `_tabController.animateTo` , the method `_handleTabChange` is executed then it just animate to the first tab.

Remove or comment this line

```
 _tabController.addListener(_handleTabChange);
```

And it should work

Comment: Thanks for the response. But this is just a test example, and what I want to do is that programmatically change the tab.
So I expected to change the tab to LEFT right after I swipe to RIGHT, but I don't understand why the TabBarView part doesn't change.

Comment: you can change the tab programmatically using  _tabController
                .animateTo   , like you are doing when you press the FloatingActionButton, but you have to remove or comment the line I told you in my answer :)